# Date / Time differs on U.S and E.U PC's - Delphi doesn't like that

Tags: delphi, datetime

I am using DateTime values in my program. Everything works fine on my danish Windows 7, when using them - however, when I send my app to someone with a U.S based PC (with the different Date/Time format), it blows up. I get those xx-xx-xx is not a valid date and time value" (or something like that).

I tried setting the LongDateFormat and the DateSeparator values at the startup of my program, however that doesen't work either?

What do I have to do, so that my app will have the same date/time format, no matter where its being run from?

EDIT: Here's what I do to create the DateTime value:

```
// David's Suggestion:
dtLastOnline := dedtLastOnline.Date + tpLastOnline.Time;
```

Thanks

- Jeff

Comment: I removed the [Delphi] from the start of your question title, that's what the tags are for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to store dates and times in a standard format (e.g. a Delphi `TDateTime`). You only convert them to human readable forms when you display them.

After your edit to clarify, what you need to do is to convert the date and time separately and then add together the two resulting `TDateTime` values.

So your code should be:

```
dedtLastOnline.Date + tpLastOnline.Time
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing that already - however I have an editbox that picks the Date, and another editbox that picks the time, whereafter I try to fuse them using the FormatDateTime - is that what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You convert the date to `TDateTime`, the time to `TDateTime` and then add the two `TDateTime` variables together.

Comment: I just edited the O.P so you can see what I am currently doing - is that wrong?

Comment: My comment already answered your question before your edit. But I've edited the answer which hopefully makes it even clearer.

Comment: The dedtLastOnline.Date and tpLastOnline.Time are both TDateTime values - so does your answer still do the trick? (I ask beause I am not sure if you are aware of that)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I reread the comments, and I realize that it will. :)

Comment: @Jeff It's just yet another one of those things that you need to know. `TDateTime = type Double` so you can perform arithmetic on them. They measure time and date in units of days. `tpLastOnline.Time` should be in the range [0.0..1.0]

Comment: @David - This did not really solve my problem afterall - still getting the ".. is not a valid date and time value"

Comment: @Jeff, can you show us the code you are using following @David suggestion. That should really work. :S

Comment: @Jeff Well, I answered this question. Perhaps you've got a new question!!

Comment: @Guillem Yes, will edit. @David Well, original question was to fix the error, which has not been solved yet. ;)

Comment: @Jeff It's a new question really. If you edit it enormously then it just makes this answer look stupid.

Comment: @David What do you want me to call the new question then, since it's basically the same question

Comment: @Jeff I don't know what the new question is, and I don't know why you still have problems because I don't know what other code you have. All I know is that if you want to combine a date and a time then you add the `TDateTime` values rather than concatenating string representations. That was this question. If you have another question then we can all have a go at that.

Comment: @David - New question added. I am just used to the Forum Rules "Don't create a new thread everytime!!" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get that "is not a valid date and time value" error?
Seems a "string to TDatetime" conversion error, which has nothing to do with a ".Date + .Time" calculation.
Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: This has already been fixed mate. It was because I was doing those StrToDateTime and other way around. :)