# "xx-xx-xx is not a valid date and time value" Error

Tags: delphi, datetime

Following up from my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015852/date-time-differs-on-u-s-and-e-u-pcs-delphi-doesent-like-that), I still get the error whenever I run it on a system with a different date/time format. I am using a Date Edit, and a Time Edit-box to select my date and time value. The Date Edit is formatted as `dd-mm-yy`, and my Time Edit is formated as `hh:mm`. When I save them to the TDateTime variable `dtLastOnline` I get the 'xx-xx-xx is not a valid date and time value' error.

I set my dtLastOnline like `dtLastOnline := dedtLastOnline.Date + tpLastOnline.Time;`

How to I make sure my app has the same Date/Time format wherever it is being run from?

I tried setting the ShortDateFormat, LongDateFormat, etc, but that won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: You have not yet given us the line of code where the error occurs. The code you have offered is a simple floating point addition. Also, you don't want your app to have the same date/time format wherever it is run from. You want to use the format that is appropriate to the locale of the user. I can't understand American dates, and Americans can't understand British dates. Don't force your locale onto others, it won't work!

Comment: It also looks to me like you should apply `Trunc()` to the Date value and subtract `Trunc(Time)` from the Time value so that they are in the appropriate range. You want the integral part of Date and the fractional part of Time.

Comment: @David - I can't tell where the program breaks, as it is not on my PC. I am currently installing all my components on my laptop, that funny enough uses the U.S format. Will debug on there.

Comment: @David - I wont force my locale onto others, once I get this working ;)

Comment: It won't break on the line you have shown here, I can assure you of that. But please do take on board my advice about sticking to the system locale. You just need to work internally with `TDateTime` and only have strings for user input (TDateTimePicker handles all of that) and any time you display to user (call FormatDateTime). Of course, let's worry about UTC and local time some other time (sic!)

Comment: @David - Yes, thats basically all I am doing now, but I still get the error.

Comment: Your error message suggests that you somewhere is using `FloatToDateTime` or a `Variant` with a value outside the range of `MinDateTime` and `MaxDateTime`. What is your exact error message?

Comment: @Mikael (dummy date) "16-02-11 00:00" is not a valid date and time

Comment: Or you are you converting from `string` to `TDateTime` somewhere using `StrToDateTime`?

Comment: @Mikael - yes, I am. I am doing DateTimeToStr when saving my datetime, and StrToDateTime when loading them

Comment: @Jeff - StrToDateTime accepts a TFormatSettings, have you tried that?

Comment: You should be able to see if that is the place where you get the exception instead of the date assignment.

Comment: @Mikael I think it's most likely the other way around as a result of a call to `StrToDateTime`. The other possibility is from `EncodeDateTime` or `RecodeDateTime` but I think that is much less likely. Somewhere or other, Jeff will be working with a textual representation rather than a TDateTime.

Comment: @Jeff You're doing it the wrong way round! If you save as text then when you load with different locale settings you'll get the error you are encountering. Try saving the TDateTime as I already said!! ;-)

Comment: @Sertac - No, I havent. I actually got it working now. @Mikael - Yes, that was it.

Comment: @David - Yeah, I will do that! :P

Comment: @David - Since I am saving and loading my Date and Time in a single TDate Time, will the dedtLastOnline.Date (The Date Picker) still contain the Time part of the TDateTime?

Comment: @David Thanks! So, when loading and saving my TDateTime's, will I do FloatToStr instead of DateTimeToStr? and StrToFloat instead of StrToDateTime? AFAIK Double and Float is about the same?

Comment: @Jeff - I you use `FloatToStr` to persist the date you need to take care about the comma separator that is different depending on locale.

Comment: @Mikael - Yeah, I figured.. Also, apparently I still get the error even when applying all the above.

Comment: @Jeff - If it still fails I think you should update the question and show the code where the error occurs.

Comment: @Mikael - I can't even debug it, as I cant produce the error on my own PC, I have to send it to my buddy that tests it every time

Comment: @Jeff - Change regional settings in control panel to English (United States). Then you are running the same setup as he does.

Comment: @Mikael - Alright, now I get an invalid floating point value, because of the separator.

Comment: @Jeff - Now that you can test it yourself you just need to figure out how to persist a TDateTime so that it works with different locale settings. I think that is a valid question to SO and you will probably get more than one answer to choose from :) .

Comment: @Mikael Agreed, that would be a good question. I'd probably offer multiple answers!!

Comment: @Mikael - I got it working now, there was still one place in code where I used the old method. I will ask another question now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with two TDateTimePickers, one set to hold a data, and one to hold a time. Is that what you are doing?

I find that the following works for me with no errors:

```
var
  dt: TDateTime;
  ...
dt := DateOf(DatePicker.Date) + TimeOf(TimePicker.Time);
ShowMessage(FormatDateTime('c', dt));
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: @David - I have never used Trunc before, will try that

Comment: You could use `DateOf` and `TimeOf` from `DateUtils` instead. `DateOf` does `Trunc` and `TimeOf` does `Frac`.

Comment: @Mikael Silly me. Since I never do this kind of thing myself, I didn't know of those functions. Thanks a lot! I have updated.

Comment: @David - I got it working, but only by setting the LongDateFormat, etc.

Comment: @Jeff: If there's a chance of your having to deal with dates earlier than December 30, 1899, you'll have to *subtract* `TimeOf` from `DateOf`, not to add them. It's a known negative-valued date anomaly in Delphi, which is [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TDateTime).

Comment: @Andriy - Yes, I know the minimum date is December 30 1899. I am not sure what you mean by the **subtract TimeOf from DateOf, not to add them.** ?

Comment: @Jeff: December 30, 1899 is not the *minimum* date, it's a *0-valued* date in Delphi, meaning that you can have negative dates as well. And the catch with negative dates is how the time portion is stored with them. An example from the doc linked: `December 29, 1899; 6:00 A.M.`. Without the time portion the date would be stored as `-1`. The time portion is essentially a quarter of the day, so `0.25`. You would expect that the complete date/time value would then be `-1 + 0.25 = -0.75`, but in fact it's `-1.25`.

Comment: @Jeff: So, the time portion is stored in such a way that, when extracted, it can always be converted to the correct time representation. The doc states explicitly: `When working with negative TDateTime values, computations must handle time portion separately.` In your particular case it means that with negative dates you should simply replace addition with subtraction, and it'll work correctly (for negative dates).